# Make a third party class a service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm a beginner at Spring and beginning to understand how beans work. I want to declare a 3rd party class as a Service or a Bean. How do I do this? Should I just extend the class and annotate that?

example:

`@Service
public class MyService { public MyService(ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyClass){..}....}`

Here I cannot annotate ThirdPartyClass as a Service or otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your aren't the owner of the class that you would like to use as a bean, you can create the bean declaration in one of application's configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyClass() {
        return new ThirdPartyClass();
    }

}
```

Spring will instantiate an appropriate object based on that description and expose it via container to other beans.

Comment: I did this and in my Application class, I have the annotation `@SpringBootApplication` which should auto detect any `@Configuration` classes correct? However it is still not working with a "no qualifying bean error"

Comment: Actually `@SprinBootApplication` is also @Configuration class so you can put this bean declaration right inside that class. If by saying 'I did this and in my Application class' you mean you created an inner `@Configuration` class then yes, it will be detected as long as the inner class is static.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've tried both and debugging has revealed that one of my @Bean annotated methods in the Application is not being called (there are other methods alongside it and they are being called). Though I've made progress

Comment: If you don't mind.. I don't want to make another question to spam but any pointers as to why one of my Bean methods is not being called while the others are? The other ones are in the same config class as well and alongside it and they get called fine but this one method doesn't..

Comment: Basically all beans should be created so the situation you described seems odd. It would be easier to answer if you shared the actual code of that bean.

Comment: @DanielOlszewski Just a simple bean method exactly like your example only with 2 strings in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class which is out of your control as `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClassName methodName() {
        return new ClassName();
    }
}
```

At the time of initializing the application, spring will call this method and register `ClassName` object to spring context and will be made available where you `@Autowired` this bean.